# Searching MongoDB with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am using ruby 1.9.3p194 and rails 3.2.5
when i do

```
@authors = Author.all
```

it works fine by outputing all name from my database.
But

```
@authors = Author.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

is not working. I am using Mongodb. I want to output the name(Ram) when i input R.
What could be the solution?

---

By this method i can search params[:q] through my field :name only. How can i add other field name also such i want to seach this params[:q] in text field :role , :email also at once? I used || but it gives error.
I have to write this in comment but since my comment list is long . I ask this question here.
Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't use "LIKE" queries as in SQL.
You (can) use regular expressions:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

To solve your specific problem, you could use
`@authors = Author.where(name: /#{params[:q]}/)`, but I'm not entirely sure if this can be a security issue or not.

Comment: `/#{Regexp.escape(params[:q])}/` might server you better. And it is worth noting that you'll be limited to the regexes that MongoDB supports rather than Ruby's.

Comment: DO u have any idea that search condition works for capital letter also. I mean to say( if a then it displays all associated data including capital letter also) for ex a->apple,Aeroplane

Comment: To make it case insensitive, add a "i" to the end, like this: `/#{Regexp.escape(params[:q])}/i`

Comment: can we code it such that if one data is choosen then it will not display second time. for example i choose m(results mongo monkey) and mongo is chhosen there. and in second time also if i choose m then only monkey should be displayed . I am using jquery token. might i have to change in js or here i am confused.

Comment: @regmiprem probably, but that should be another question

Comment: ya it should be another question but do you have any idea about this. Since u are giving awesome answers so i think that by posting this question here, i can connect u directly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154136/any-idea-not-to-select-the-name-that-is-already-choosen-in-token-input

Comment: By this method i can search params[:q] through my field :name only. How can i add other field name also such i want to seach this params[:q] in text field :role , :email also at once? I used || but it gives error. I have to write this in comment but since my comment list is long . I ask this question here. Sorry for that.