# Any idea not to select the name that is already chosen in token input?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, jquery-tokeninput

Is there any idea not to select the name that is already chosen in token input? For example In first I select mango when I search for m. Next time again when I search for m Mango should not be displayed as mango is already chosen. Is there any idea?

```
 <%= f.text_field :plan_tokens, data: {load: @customer.plans} %>
```

I have my js like this
jQuery ->

```
 $('#customer_plan_tokens').tokenInput '/plans.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#customer_plan_tokens').data('load')
```

where to put preventDuplicates:true. I did try but error arise!

I study this from

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize tokeninput in your JavaScript, you can add `preventDuplicates: true` and this will prevent duplicates from being selected, but they'll still be shown in the results ([demo](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html#prevent-duplicates)).

So something like:

```
$(...).tokenInput("url", { preventDuplicates: true, otherOptionsHere });
```

If you don't want them shown at all, it would probably be possible to write some code for the `onResult` callback that checks the value of the field and removes the ones that are already there.

**edit**: since you use CoffeeScript, try

```
$('#customer_plan_tokens').tokenInput '/plans.json'
   theme: 'facebook'
   prePopulate: $('#customer_plan_tokens').data('load')
   preventDuplicates: true
```

Comment: this script blocks all data to add later.It only allow 1 data to be selected. for example at first when i such for f it gives face,fossil.I choose face. again when i chose f then it displays face,fossil but at that time it blocks fossil also to be selected.

Comment: preventDuplicates: true blocks all next chosen data to select .

Comment: I've never used tokeninput, so I'm not entirely sure, but since the demo works fine, I'm guessing it is somewhere on your end. What does your JSON response look like?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what u mean to say. can u please describe me in details.

Comment: tokenInput loads the data to be displayed from `/plans.json`, but what does the response you get look like?

Comment: [{"_id":"5004e9736d7ab86d0d000001","article_ids":[],"born":null,"content":null,"name":"bijay"},{"_id":"500528c66d7ab8480e000004","article_ids":[],"born":null,"content":null,"name":"M...... from here it take id and display the name . It passes the id of the name that is chosen to the database.

Comment: The documentation for Tokeninput says to return objects that has a "id" field, and not "_id", so you might try to include both, and see if that helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15957/discussion-between-perfectlynormal-and-regmiprem)